# Dragging nested components into a diagram in Sparx Enterprise Architect (EA)

Tags: components, modeling, enterprise-architect

In my Enterprise Architect model, I have **nodes** that contain **devices** that contain **components** that contain **other components**. That's how I organized the hierarchy in the Project Browser.

I would like to be able to **drag one element** of the model into a diagram (as a Link), and be able to **see all the elements** contained by this element without having to drag them individually. For example, dragging a device into a deployment diagram would display the node and all the components it contains.

This logic works when I drag a component onto a diagram: I am able to select what children elements (interfaces, ports, ...) I want to see on the diagram. But I did not find a way to do the same with this following containment hierarchy: node > device > component > subcomponent.

Is there a way to do so ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it manually, of course. Dragging the outermost onto the diagram (as link) and enlarge it. Drag the inner ones onto the diagram somewhere outside the outer one (to avoid some dialog otherwise). Drag them inside the outer and arrange as needed.

[image]

Another way is to make the outer element composite (context/Add/Composite diagram or /New Diagram/Composite). On this composite diagram place the inner elements and arrange them. Save the diagram when done. Now you can create diagrams with the outer element which, once enlarged, can show the composite diagram inside. Just drag the composite diagram as Diagram Frame and eventually make it smaller. Then place it inside the enlarged outer component.

[image]

While in the first case you can show relations (like port delegation) this is not possible in the second one.

There is no way to automagically drop the nested structure except you come up with some very tricky add-in.